# Have I completely removed BitTorrent and all the junk that came with it?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, malware, torrent

I tried to install BitTorrent to download some Linux ISO files, but I clicked through the install screens too fast, and missed the part where it said that it would install browser addons and other junk. I removed the BitTorrent application by deleting the .app file, removed the browser addons, and reset my home page and search engine. I also ran Malwarebytes and it found some adware, so I had it remove them. Then I rebooted and ran the scan again, and it found one more piece of adware, which it then removed. After rebooting again, Malwarebytes says that it can't find anything. Is there anything else I need to do to completely remove BitTorrent and all the junk that it installed?

I'm on a 2013 MacBook Pro running OS X 10.11.6

UPDATE:
The actual app that I installed was called BitTorrent. I didn't download anything with it.

UPDATE 2:
I downloaded Bitdefender Virus Scanner from the App Store and ran it on my entire hard drive. It said that my Mac was clean.

Comment: WHat exactly do you mean by BitTorrent - there are several apps that support this protocol

Comment: The actual app called BitTorrent. Sorry I didn't make this clear.

Comment: A help article from [BitTorrent](http://help.bittorrent.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1605936-removing-advertising-offers?b_id=3884) on how to remove advertising offers.

Comment: I already did that stuff, I'm just worried that there is something else that sneaked onto my Mac since Malwarebytes detected adware after I did that.